# MySQL: Insert one column data to another

Tags: mysql

I'm not soo good at MySQL. But want to improve it a bit, to be able to manipulate tables without serverside languages.

I have one table and two columns. I need to select data from one column and insert in the same table as rows instead.

As I understand I need to select this column data, save it in a temporary table or variable, then loop through results and insert them. But I do not know how to do it.

Could someone help with a simple example.

Thanks ;)

---

My table:

```
id | col1 | col2
-----------------
1  | txt  |  txt4
2  | txt2 |  txt5
3  | txt3 |  txt6
```

I need to merge col1 and col2.

Final result:

```
 id | col1
-----------
 1  |  txt
 2  |  txt2
 3  |  txt3
 4  |  txt4
 5  |  txt5
 6  |  txt6
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the initial data and the desired result, so that we can understand better?

Comment: Just tired to write this crap on php while i can do it on pure mysql... Can someone to suggest a good book for advanced data manipulation inside mysql cmd? thanks ;)

Comment: @Beck, I think what Don was looking for was a sample 'After' table as well... in particular, are you looking to concatenate them col2 and col1? Or are you looking to add col2 as rows, with the col2 values moved to col1?

Comment: Yes. "col2 values moved to col1"

Comment: @Beck please also show us, as @Don and @Dancrumb have asked, what the table should look like *after* the operation is complete.

Comment: Ops sorry updated the main post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work

```
insert into tablename
(col1_name)
select (col2_name) from tablename;
```

That will select all of your data from column 2 and insert it into column 1 as new rows. Then, you can drop the second column by doing:

```
alter table tablename drop col2_name;
```

Simply replace `tablename` with the name of your table, and the column names with the name of your column. Also, make sure that both column datatypes are compatible with each other.

Good luck!

Comment: I wish it could be so easy :) getting syntax error near select

Comment: Ekhm if remove VALUES from statement. Then it works. Thanks mate. Works perfectly! ;) Edit your post and remove VALUES so that others won't be confused.

Comment: -1 that will double the number of rows in table `tablename`, use update instead.

Comment: @Johan I think that's what the OP wanted, but it wasn't initially clear.

Comment: That was alot easier than the way I was trying, worked great. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 5):

If I am reading correct, you want to merge col1 and col2?? then, try this

```
alter table table1 add column col3 varchar(255);

update table1 set col3 = concat(col1, " ", col2);

alter table table1 drop column col1;
alter table table1 drop column col2;
```

Comment: +1, but note that in strict SQL mode you **must** have a `where` clause in your update statement. `update table1 set col3 = concat(col1, " ", col2) where id > 0` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
update table1 set column2=column1;
```